# Get and Show image from firebase storage in a listview?

Tags: java, android, listview, firebase-storage, android-volley

I am trying to get and show images from firebase storage and display it in a Listview. Most parts of the code work, retrieving the images from firebase storage is successful but  only the Imageview of the first row in the Listview is loaded and shown. How do all the images get shown in all rows in the listview not just the first row?  I tried saving the links to each user in a `hm.put("listview_image", String.valueOf(mountainsRef));` but displaying them in the Listview according to each user has been a problem for me. below is the complete code, Please help me.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_users);

    usersList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.usersList);
    noUsersText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.noUsersText);

    pd = new ProgressDialog(Users.this);
    pd.setMessage(""+getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(R.string.loading));
    pd.show();

    String url = "https://PinBall-b9k94-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/users.json";

    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>(){
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String s) {
            doOnSuccess(s);
        }
    },new Response.ErrorListener(){
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
            System.out.println("" + volleyError);
        }
    });

    RequestQueue rQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(Users.this);
    rQueue.add(request);

    usersList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            UserDetails.chatWith = al.get(position);
            startActivity(new Intent(Users.this, Chat.class));

        }
    });
}

public void doOnSuccess(String s){
    try {
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(s);

        Iterator i = obj.keys();
        String key = "";

        while(i.hasNext()){
            key = i.next().toString();

            if(!key.equals(UserDetails.username)) {
                al.add(key);
                HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();
                hm.put("listview_title", key);
                hm.put("listview_discription", key);

                FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
                StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReference();
                StorageReference mountainsRef = storageRef.child(key+".jpg");
                hm.put("listview_image", String.valueOf(mountainsRef));
                aList.add(hm);

                StorageReference uri = storageRef.child(key+".jpg");
                uri.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                        // Set the profile picture using the download URL
                        ImageView ProfilePicture2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.listview_image);
                        Picasso.get().load(uri).into(ProfilePicture2);
                    }
                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                        // Handle any errors
                    }
                });
            }

            totalUsers++;
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if(totalUsers <=1){
        noUsersText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        usersList.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    else{
        noUsersText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        usersList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        String[] from = {"listview_image", "listview_title", "listview_discription"};
        int[] to = {R.id.listview_image, R.id.listview_item_title, R.id.listview_item_short_description};

        SimpleAdapter simpleAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), aList, R.layout.listview_activity, from, to);
        ListView androidListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.usersList);
        androidListView.setAdapter(simpleAdapter);

    }

    pd.dismiss();
}
```

}